# Can you run a background iBeacon/Eddystone scan in web-bluetooth using a service worker?

Tags: javascript, web, bluetooth, beacon, web-bluetooth

With the release of new web-bluetooth features, I believe iBeacon/Eddystone beacon scanning is possible in PWAs using web-bluetooth. I am running a use-case and I would like some help on achieving a background service worker, which scans for beacons in background using chrome service-workers or something similar in smartphones?

Is this possible and if yes how?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

According to the Chrome feature status page, the Web Bluetooth scanning feature has not been implemented at all as of May 2019.  **This makes it impossible to scan for beacons**: https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md#scanning-api

There are other APIs implemented that let you find and connect to Bluetooth devices, but because you cannot see and decode the advertisements (what the above unimplemented API would provide), you cannot use them as beacons.